# Parsing soap response from asp

Tags: soap, vbscript

I have a soap request returning a response like below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:authkeyResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:authkey">
    <return xsi:type="xsd:string">ALREADY REGISTERED</return>
    </ns1:authkeyResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am invoking the soap using vb script by following the example from http://kapie.com/2007/consuming-soap-web-services-from-vbscript.  I get this whole xml in the strSoapReq object but not sure how to parse it so that I can popup only the result which is "ALREADY REGISTERED".

Comment: Can you provide the code your working on? Not sure where you are stuck. From the page you linked you should get the return value by using the `GetResult(byval responseText, byval resultParam)` function. `resultParam` should then be `return`.

Comment: I guess GetResult should be called explicitly and am not sure of what kind of parameters to pass to it.

Comment: It has to be called explicitly. Takes 2 parameters. The first one is your SOAP/XML string result. The second one is the _name_ of the element which contents you want to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example from the link you gave, make sure you call `GetResult` explicitly.

If you followed the example and based on your SOAP result, it should be:

`GetResult(strResult, "result")`