# Parse XML Soap Response with vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing, asp-classic, msxml

I am sending in a XML request to a third party API and I get a response back that I need to parse to either get the error message or get the success and order id.

Here is the response I get back from an error message.

```xml
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<soap:envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:body>
      <createbackgroundcheckresponse xmlns="https://www.website.com/sif/ws/hrxml/2.0">
         <applicationacknowledgement>
            <payloadresponsesummary>
            <payloaddisposition>
               <entitydisposition>
                  <entityinstancexpath>/Order/SearchPackage[1]/ReferenceId[1]/IdValue[1] </entityinstancexpath>
                  <entityexception>
                     <exception>
                        <exceptionidentifier>02x0033</exceptionidentifier>
                        <exceptionseverity>Fatal</exceptionseverity>
                        <exceptionmessage>An order is already being processed with the same user</exceptionmessage>
                     </exception>
                  </entityexception>
               </entitydisposition>
            </payloaddisposition>
         </payloadresponsesummary></applicationacknowledgement>
      </createbackgroundcheckresponse>
   </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

I am able to get the response and write it to the browser but can't parse through it.  Here is what I have when I send it.

```vb
Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

xmlHttp.Open "POST", xUrl, False         'False = Synckronous Process
xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-type", contentType
xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(xmlBody)

xmlHttp.SetOption 2, 13056          'Ignore SSL errors
xmlHttp.Send xmlBody

'Get the response back
sRet = xmlHttp.ResponseText

If xmlHttp.ReadyState = 4 And xmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
    HttpPOST = sRet
Else
    HttpPOST = "[Http-Failure] " & vbNewLine & sRet
End If
```

Once I get the data back here is what I have.

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")

xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.ResolveExternals = False
xmlDoc.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlDoc.ValidateOnParse = True
xmlDoc.PreserveWhiteSpace = True

If xmlDoc.LoadXML(sRet) Then
    'Dim xmlNodeList
    Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("exceptionmessage")
    If Not (xmlNodeList Is Nothing) Then
        response.Write "exceptionmessage is Not Nothing<P>"
        If xmlNodeList.Length > 0 Then
            response.Write "xmlNodeList length > 0<P>"
            Response.Write "exceptionmessage Value is : " & xmlNodeList(0).Text & vbNewLine & "<BR>"
        Else
            Response.Write "exceptionmessage length is 0<P>"
        End If
    Else
        response.Write "exceptionmessage is Nothing<P>"
    End If

    Set nodeXML = Nothing
End If
```

When I run that it will get past the `xmlDoc.LoadXML()`.  Then it will get past the first check of `If Not (xmlNodeList is Nothing) Then`.  But then the length of that is 0 so it can't get pass that part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing soap response from asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495503/parsing-soap-response-from-asp)

Comment: VBScript's XML parser fails silently when it encounters an error. Check the value of `xmlDoc.ParseError`. If the result is not 0 also check the value of `xmlDoc.ParseError.Reason`.

Comment: VBScript does not have an "XML parser."  You seem to be talking about the MSXML v. 3 DOM, which is part of Windows and not VBScript, and isn't a parser but a DOM.  The preferred way to process SOAP in VBScript is to use the deprecated SOAP Toolkit 3.0, which operates at a higher level than generic XML processing.  You might also consider the 3rd party PocketSOAP library.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things are going on here.

1) Check the error processing from the XML parser by looking at the return code from LoadXML, and then inspect the parseError object if the return code is false to figure out what's wrong.

2) SOAP XML uses namespaces (IMHO unnecessarily), to query with name spaces I use XPath (SelectionLanguage=XPath), then set SelectionNameSpaces to the URL.  Your XML uses a "default" namespace, but to query with it you need to name it something, I picked "ns" but it could be anything.  Finally, use selectNodes or selectSingleNode to query and inspect the results.

```
  Dim xml As Object

  Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

  Dim bReturn As Boolean
  bReturn = xml.Load("c:\\temp\testsoap.xml")
  If (bReturn = False) Then
    MsgBox ("Error loading XML Response: " + CStr(xml.parseError.errorCode) + " " + xml.parseError.reason)
  End If

  Call xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")
  Call xml.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns='https://www.website.com/sif/ws/hrxml/2.0'")

  Dim ndException As Object
  Set ndException = xml.selectSingleNode("//ns:exception")
  If (ndException Is Nothing) Then
    ' it worked
  Else
    MsgBox ("Exception found in XML: " + ndException.Text)
  End If
```